# fb:registration possible to set date range or select future date?

Tags: facebook, registration

I create a registration on my site with FB registration plugin. I use a `'type':'date'` field for "planned future event date". This date is a future date, but the default DATE field lists years only backwards. 
It is possible to set a daterange, or set at least +1 year (eg. 2013)?

thanks.